# Should the visitor pattern be used for rendering?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a game engine that currently uses inheritance to provide a generic interface to do rendering:

```
class renderable
{
public:
    void render();
};
```

Each class calls the `gl_*` functions itself, this makes the code hard to optimize and hard to implement something like setting the quality of rendering:

```
class sphere : public renderable
{
public:
    void render()
    {
        glDrawElements(...);
    }
};
```

I was thinking about implementing a system where I would create a `Renderer` class that would render my objects:

```
class sphere
{
    void render( renderer* r )
    {
        r->renderme( *this );
    }
};

class renderer
{
    renderme( sphere& sphere )
    {
         // magically get render resources here
         // magically render a sphere here
    }
};
```

My main problem is where should I store the VBOs and where should I Create them when using this method?
Should I even use this approach or stick to the current one, perhaps something else?

Comment: This will destroy performance if you're calling virtual functions like this in your render loop. Your icache is going to miss nearly every call unless you sort by dynamic type.

Comment: @Simple In which implementation will the cache miss? And what's your suggestion then?

Comment: When you call `render` you're going to cache miss because the function isn't in in the icache so it has to load it in. Then you call `render` again but its a different function this time, so cache miss again; throw out the old function and load the new one in. `render` again, oh look it's the function we just threw out... You can sort by `typeid(x).hash_code()` as a general solution not specific to graphics so all objects with the same `render` functions are together. The proper way in graphics is to use instanced draw calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm neither a GameEngine nor a C++ performance expert, so take this with a grain of salt)

There are some existing game engines that use the visitor approach, e.g. [GamePlay3D](https://github.com/blackberry/GamePlay/wiki/Tutorial%3a-Spaceship#rendering-the-game). For performance reasons, you probably should exclude non-visible objects from the rendering routine.